# Java, How to change a value in every constructor object in a class?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to make a game and for the gun class, I need every bullet to be a constructor object, how do I edit every constructor at once? Like change each bullet's x value?

Comment: What do you mean a "constructor object"? And what is your actual intention? I'm quite sure you have a solution in mind, but what's the problem it's solving?

Comment: I meant an insistence of an object, and let's say I create a lot of bullets and they are all in the air, how do I increase every one's x value relative to it's on, so that one with an x of 13 would be 14 and one with a value of 6 would be 7. I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's me make a hard guess.

```
class Gun{
  Bullet bullet;
  public Gun(){
   bullet = new Bullet();
  }
}
class Bullet{
 public int x=0;
 public Bullet(){
   x=10;
 }
}
```

You want to change all the Bullet's x value at once(As I understood). Then you have to keep all the Bullet instances in a data structure.

```
static List<Bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
```

Then update the constructor of Bullet like below.

```
class Bullet{
 public int x=0;
 public Bullet(){
   x=10;
   Gun.bullets.add(this);
 }
}
```

Then iterate through the bullets list and make the change you want to make.

```
for(Iterator i = bullets.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
 i.next().x = 12;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. It would be great if you can mark this answer as correct since it'll be easy for user to find out the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of a constructor. A constructor is called when an instance of a class is made and usually initializes properties for that single instance. If you want to change the values of all the instances of an object, you will have to store references in an array (or other similar data structure) then iterate over them and change each value individually.

Comment: Didn't he say he wants to change *all* Bullet object's `x` values? This is only initialize x.

Comment: Do you mean like a polymorphic array?

Comment: @user1294270 could enlighten us as to what exactly is a ` polymorphic array`.

Comment: Why the downvote? The accepted answer gives code for exactly what I said.

Answer (score 0):

No iteration over bullets.  No, no, a million times, no.  *Encapsulate* the value of `x` so you only have to make a change once.  Here is a simple code example that illustrates the design pattern you should be thinking of.  Google "publish-subscribe pattern" or "observer pattern" for the full idea.

```
public class Bullet {
    public static int globalEffect = 0;
    private int myX;
    public int x() { 
     return myX + globalEffect;
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that one expects that bullets fired at different times will have traveled different distances (assuming that `x` is the position of the bullet).  One also expects that bullets fired from different guns will have different initial velocities and be affected differently by friction.  This approach would not support any of those.

Comment: @aroth - then there should be private var's initial velocity and coefficient of friction and some math in `x()`.  Anything that can be accomplished with iteration can by achieved by putting the same effect inside an accessor

Answer (score -1):

Collect your bullets as you create them, and then iterate the collection to update them.  For instance, something like:

```
public abstract class Projectile {
    private static final Collection<Projectile> activeProjectiles = new ArrayList<Projectile>();

    static {
         //update the position of any in-flight projectile approximately once per second
         Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 while (true) {
                     synchronized(activeProjectiles) {
                         for (Projectile projectile : new ArrayList<Projectile>(activeProjectiles)) {
                             projectile.travel();
                         }
                     }
                     try {
                         Thread.sleep(1000);
                     }
                     catch (Throwable ignored) {}
                 }
             }
         };
         new Thread(updater).start();
    }

    protected int x;
    protected int transitTime;

    public abstract int getMuzzleVelocity();

    public Projectile() {
        this.x = 0;
        synchronized(activeProjectiles) {
            activeProjectiles.add(this);
        }
    }

    public int getFriction() {
        return 0;
    }

    private void travel() {
        this.x += this.getMuzzleVelocity() + (this.getFriction() * this.transitTime);
        this.transitTime++;
        if (this.transitTime * this.getFriction() >= this.getMuzzleVelocity()) {
            //this projectile is done
            synchronized(activeProjectiles) {
                activeProjectiles.remove(this);
            }
        }

    }

}

public class Bullet extends Projectile {
    public Bullet() { 
        super();
    } 

    @Override
    public int getMuzzleVelocity() {
         return 600;
    }

    @Override
    public int getFriction() {
        return 25;
    }
}
```